# Can't print double byte characters with Windows command prompt

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, printing, windows-vista

I am using an old software that requires printing from a dos-like command prompt environment, and the software requires to print out double-byte characters like Japanese font to the default printer. However, every time I try printing, the characters show up like gibberish (mojibake) and can't get the Japanese to show up properly on
 the physical paper. In other words if I print a file called test.txt, with something like the following inside the test.txt content...

```
----------------
Hello
日本語です。
English
----------------
```

The single-byte characters like "Hello and English" shows up fine, but not "日本語です。"
The Japanese characters will be displayed like {*}+{~= on physical paper. 
(Btw, I just used the command "print.exe test.txt" in command prompt.)

Note I have no problem printing from a MS word document or even a text doc.

Furthermore, I am using the ESC/P printer (Epson GP-710). Also by default, since
the cmd.exe prints to LPT1 by default, I mapped it to a network printer
so it can print to a USB (I'm pretty sure this does not have anything to 
do with the font problem), by doing something like below.

1）Share printer
2) `NET USE LPT1: \\(PChostname123)\(printername) /PERSISTENT:YES`

I use both Windows 7 (64 bit) and Windows Vista, and the same problem
occurs on both. I have read articles on Japanese websites that states 
Windows 95 dos there was a workaround by adding text in the Config.sys file 
or autoexec.bat file, but it didn't seem like it will work on Windows NT versions.

As I really have no choice but to use this old program for now, it would be
really grateful if anybody knows about double-byte character printing
from dos/cmd prompts.

Comment: you might try to start the DOS programme in an Unicode command processor `cmd /U`, see `cmd /?`. I don't know if that would work.

Comment: your problem is: your printer understands "english chars" only. It works with Word, because Word prints graphics instead of text. You will have to tell your printer to use japanese instead of english (see handbook / don't know if your printer is able to). Also Endoro's hint *might* work.

Answer (score 2):

At the beginning of your batch file, try adding the following line:

```
chcp 65001
```

This will set the code page to UTF-8.  It will not display properly in a command prompt, but may print correctly depending on your printer.

For more on code pages see [this wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) or for a complete list of Microsoft values see [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).